# Model validation is checking required fields in a referenced model object, when the key is only required one

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-validation

I'm creating an edit form for a Student model:

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual StudentGuardian Guardian { get; set; }
}
```

This Student has a StudentGuardian instance inside, the StudentGuardian has validation attributes on Name, Sex ... etc

```
public class StudentGuardian
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual string MobilePhone { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Sex Sex { get; set; }
}
```

But at Student edit form I'm only interested in GuardianId. The point is when creating an edit form and make something like that in the form:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Student.Guardian.ID, <GUARDIANS_LIST>)
```

and since the Guardian object is required at Student model, so the MVC validation is asking me to enter Guardian.Name and Guardian.MobilePhone  and etc,

How can I just enforce the validation to be Guardian.Id only not the entire object?

Comment: Create a different view model that is relevant to this view? That's the whole point of a view model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sole idea of keeping `StudentGuardian`in `Student` is to create a 1-to-1 relationship between `Student` and `StudentGuardian` classes and not for rendering data to the `view`. By  your approach you will be getting errors not only while editing the student entity but also while creating it. Trying using a view model as others have recommended. The following is just an attempt to help you understand better.

```
public class StudentViewModel
{
        public int StudentId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        //..other member variables..

        [Display(Name="Guardian"]
        public int GuardianId { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<StudentGuardian> Guardians { get; set; }

}
```

And then in your `Edit` Action of your Controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        Student student = db.Students.Find(id);
        var model = new StudentViewModel();
        model.Name = student.Name;
        model.Guardians = db.Guardians.ToList();

        //or if using repository then call the method that fetches
        //.. you the list of objects 
        //..and bind it to the StudentViewModel instance created.

        //Other Properties you need..fetch and assign them here..
        //model.StudentId= student.Id; ... etc


        if (student == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(model); // return the viewModel instance.
    }
```

Bind your `Edit View` with the `StudentViewModel` as well.

```
@model MvcApplication.Models.ViewModels.StudentViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Student</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.StudentId)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GuardianId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GuardianId)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GuardianId, new SelectList(Model.Guardians, "GuardianId", "GuardianName"),"Select")
        </div>


        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Receive the data back on a reference of `StudentViewModel` class

```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Edit(StudentViewModel model)
    {
          //..do whatever..Save to Database or something else..
    }
```

Try googling for ViewModels, you will get numerous resources.